# DocumentDB adding an univocal document in parallel WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

this is my scenario: I've an azure queue, a pool of web jobs and a DocumentDB collection. In the queue there are some messages processed by the webjobs.

The webjob processes a message then it create a document on DocumentDB only if the name in the queue message does not already contained in a document into the db.
Each name in the documents must be unique so if the webjob checks the presence of a document with the same name in the queue message, it reads this document and it increases a counter.

The problem is that the webjob works in parallel with other same webjobs so two or more instances can read different queue messages at the same time that contain the same name (not already into db). To ensure the uniqueness of the names in the documents I've created this pre-trigger on DocumentDb

```
function validateName() {
  var collection = getContext().getCollection();
  var request = getContext().getRequest();
  var docToCreate = request.getBody();

  lookForDuplicates();

  function lookForDuplicates(continuation) {
    var query = {
      query: 'SELECT * FROM myCollection c WHERE c.GeoArea.Name = @Name',
      parameters: [{
        name: '@Name',
        value: docToCreate.GeoArea.Name
      }]
    };
    var requestOptions = {
      continuation: continuation
    };

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query, requestOptions,
      function(err, results, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error('Error querying for documents with duplicate Name: ' + err.message);
        }
        if (results.length > 0) {
          throw new Error('Document with the name, ' + docToCreate.GeoArea.Name + ', already exists: ' + JSON.stringify(results[0]));
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This pre-trigger almost always works but sometimes happen that I found in the db two documents with the same name. Why?

Comment: I can't see how it would cause you problem, but why is the continuation in there? You don't seem to use it. Not sure how DocumentDB behaves with continuation = null. Another thought, have you tried moving your trigger and update logic all into the same sproc?

Comment: Is there some place in your code where you fail to explicitly list the trigger? I favor sprocs over triggers for validation because I am afraid that myself or some other dev will fail to list the trigger in their code.

Comment: could it be a classic race condition? you have two processes, at exactly the same time each look for doc with name=="foo" neither finds it, both insert it. problem.

to resolve this you would need to create some sort of semaphore that guarantees only one process can be working at exactly the same time.